# Proof verification for Cesàro convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I've recently encountered in this other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3889057/505767) the following statement:

> Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded non-negative real sequence, then
> $$
> \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0 \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} x_i=0
> $$

for which I've provided the following partial proof.

(I've already posted that in the previous question but then deleted because the asker was not seeking for a proof but only for a previous reference).

Firstly note that by $2^n=N$ the following holds

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} x_i=0 \iff  \lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=N}^{2N-1} x_i=0$$

then we proceed with the proof separetely for the two implications.

**1)** Proof for $\implies$

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=n}^{2n-1} x_i=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i=\frac{2n-1}{n}\frac{1}{2n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} x_i-\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i\to 0$$

**2)** Proof for $\impliedby$

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n-1} x_i=\frac{2n-1}{n}\frac{1}{2n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n-1} x_i$$

$$\iff \frac{2n-1}{n}\frac{1}{2n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n-1} x_i=\frac{1}{n}\left(-x_n+\sum_{i=n}^{2n-1} x_i\right)\to 0$$

> I'm stuck here: how can we conclude from the last identity that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \to 0$. That is: how can we assume that this latter limit exists? It is trivially true when the limit for $x_i$ exists but what about the general case? Can we conclude the proof by this way or we need to use a completely different approach?

---

EDIT

I've added the condition that $x_i\ge 0$ after an update for the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write a chain of (correct) identities where the last one is:
$$
\frac{2n-1}{n}\frac{1}{2n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=\frac{1}{n}\left(-x_n+\sum_{i=n}^{2n-1} x_i\right).
$$
Now, you wrote that the last term above $\frac{1}{n}\left(-x_n+\sum_{i=n}^{2n-1} x_i\right)$ tends to $0$ by using the fact (by a your previous comment in the deleted answer) that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1}x_i=\ell \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=N}^{2N-1}x_i=\ell.\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(*)
$$
However, this is *false*.

A counterexample to (*) is the $\{0,1\}$-valued sequence, where $x_n=1$ if and only if $3\cdot 2^k\le n<3\cdot 2^{k+1}$ for some $k$ even. Now, the "if" implication is trivial. However, the "only if" does not hold: indeed, fix $k$ even. Then, for $N=2^k$ we have $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=N}^{2N-1}x_i=\frac{1}{2}$, while for $N=3\cdot 2^k$ we have $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=N}^{2N-1}x_i=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I need to take a closer look to that! Maybe it is simple but at the moment I can't see how (*) is false :O

Comment: Let me add the details

Comment: Ah ok! Now it is clear. The first summation sweeps only defined intervals of $\mathbb N$ while the second one sweeps all  $\mathbb N$, therefore only the$ \impliedby$ part holds. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, correct. Again, a fortiori, the equivalence (*) is true for $\ell=0$.

Comment: And what about the proof presented here with $\ell=0$? This issue should be  overtaken now.

Comment: For the reverse implication, aren't we assuming that as hypotesis? Maybe I'm loosing something, sorry for that and thanks for your time.

Comment: @user Your identity is: 
$$
\frac{2n-1}{n}\frac{1}{2n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=\frac{1}{n}\left(-x_n+\sum_{i=n}^{2n-1} x_i\right).
$$
You assume that $\lim_k \frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{2^k\le i<2^{k+1}}x_i=0$ and you want to prove that the right hand side above has limit $0$, To this aim, you want to show that $\lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{n\le i<2n}x_i=0$. This is not the hypothesis, because it is assumed that this holds only along the subsequence of powers of $2$.

Comment: Now, even if you prove it, the argument is still incomplete because you need to show that $s:=\lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i\le n}x_i$ *exists*, to conclude that the left hand side tends to $2s-s$.

Comment: @user We needed an additional assumption indeed, the sequence being nonnegative

Comment: I've seen the update for your answer. May I add this assumption here? In this case, is yet my proof wrong?

Comment: Surely you can add it. Yes, it is still wrong (or better, incomplete). I sum up the missing points here. Set $a_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1\le i\le n}x_i$ and $b_k:=\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{2^k\le i<2^{k+1}}x_i$. Then:
$$
\text{ }
$$
(i) You assume that $b_k\to 0$. Then why $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{n\le i< 2n}x_i \to 0$?
$$
\text{ }
$$
(ii) You would like to conclude that $a_n\to 0$. Even if you assume (i), how do you do it? (You would need the existence of $\lim_n a_n$.)

Comment: Thank you! I would like to take a look to it! And many thanks for your time and effort to explain me the issues here! Bye